# python aiohttp middleware func definition; why the difference, and what's best

Tags: python, middleware, aiohttp

Context is creating a simple python agent to collate various diverse metrics, for Prometheus to scrape. I'm using middleware to update the values.
I've come across two way of defining aiohttp middleware, both work.I'd like to better understand the differences, also which would you recommend (or maybe there's another way I've not found out yet!)

```
async def mw1(app, handler):
    async def middleware_handler(request):
        print('mw1 start')
        response = await handler(request)
        print('mw1 end')
        return response
    return middleware_handler

@web.middleware 
async def mw2(request, handler):
    print('mw2 start')
    response = await handler(request)
    print('mw2 end')
    return response

app = web.Application(middlewares=[mw1, mw2])
```

Both of these get called and work as expected. But I don't quite understand, the significance of why one uses '*app*' as a parameter and the other uses '*request*'. 
In the mw2() I can get to '*app*' if required via *request.app*. In mw1() '*request*' appears in the inner function by magic...

Just trying to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

They are almost equal.

The second form works faster (I forget exact numbers, something about 30% maybe), thus the first is deprecated.